# How to calculate average number and give subquery label

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have two table "book" and "authorCollection". Because a book may have multi-authors, I hope to get the average number of authors in table "book" which published after year 2000(inclusive).
For example:

```
Table Book:
key  year
1     2000
2     2001
3     2002
4     1999

Table authorCollection:
key author
1    Tom
1    John
1    Alex
1    Mary
2    Alex
3    Tony
4    Mary
```

The result should be (4 + 1 + 1) / 3 = 2;(key 4 publish before year 2000).
I write the following query statement, but not right, I need to get the number of result in subquery, but cannot give it a label "b", How can i solve this problem? And get the average number of author? I still confused about "COUNT(*) as count" meaning....Thanks.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) as count,  b.COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM A
WHERE key IN  (SELECT key
               FROM Book
               WHERE year >= 2000
               ) b
GROUP BY key;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, count number of `authors` for a `key` in a subquery. Next, aggregate needed values:

```
select avg(coalesce(ct, 0))
from book b
left join (
    select key, count(*) ct
    from authorcollection
    group by 1
    ) a
using (key)
where year >= 2000;
```

Comment: Is `avg` function was dropped? :)

Comment: And because of `left join` it probably have to be `avg(coalesce(ct,0))`, just compare `select avg(foo) from (select 2 as foo union select null) as bar` (result is 2.000) and `select avg(coalesce(foo, 0)) from (select 2 as foo union select null) as bar` (result is 1.000).

Comment: I have to agree once more. Thank you, the answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

A [sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c643b/16) as well as handling 'divide by zero' error:

```
select case when count(distinct book.key)=0
  then null
  else count(authorCollection.key is not null)/count(distinct book.key)
  end as avg_after_2000
from book
left join authorCollection on(book.key=authorCollection.key)
where book.year >= 2000
```